# How to change the "From" of a created appointment in Outlook COM add-in?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, com, office-interop

I'm writing an Outlook COM add-in in C#/.NET using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.  I can create a new appointment item like so:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

[...]

var appointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
appointment.Display(true);
```

However, I have 2 different accounts set up in my Outlook.  If I then go into the appointment's "Invite Attendees", the "From" always shows the first of my two Outlook accounts.

I tried setting the `.SendUsingAccount` property to the other account in my Outlook profile, which I got from the current session:

```
var accounts = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Accounts;
foreach (Outlook.Account acct in accounts) {
    if (acct.DisplayName == "[desired account display name]") {
        appointment.SendUsingAccount = acct;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, this just makes the "From" field blank in the "Invite Attendees" section rather than showing the account I set it to.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to get this to work by finding out the currently-selected folder via `Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder` and then getting its default calendar folder through `.Store.GetDefaultFolder()`.  This allowed me to create a new calendar item through the correct calendar, automatically setting the appropriate "From" address for the currently-selected folder.  Here's the code used:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

[...]

Outlook.Explorer activeExplorer = null;
Outlook.Store currentStore = null;
Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder = null;
Outlook.Items items = null;
Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = null;
try {
    // Get default calendar for currently-selected folder
    activeExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    if (activeExplorer == null) {
        throw new Exception("No active explorer.");
    }
    currentStore = activeExplorer?.CurrentFolder?.Store;
    if (currentStore == null) {
        throw new Exception("No current store.");
    }
    calendarFolder = currentStore?.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    if (calendarFolder == null) {
        throw new Exception("No default calendar folder.");
    }
    items = calendarFolder?.Items;
    if (items == null) {
        throw new Exception("No calendar folder items.");
    }

    // Populate a new outlook appointment object with the appointment info
    appointment = items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

    // Setup appointment
    [...]

    // Display the appointment window to the user
    appointment.Display(true);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(Resources.AppointmentError + ": " + ex.Message);
}
finally {
    if (activeExplorer != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(activeExplorer); }
    if (currentStore != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentStore); }
    if (calendarFolder != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(calendarFolder); }
    if (items != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items); }
    if (appointment != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the `Save` method to apply your changes made through the OOM.

The [AppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount](https://technet.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/library/ff868952%28v=office.14%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property allows to specify an Account object that represents the account under which the AppointmentItem is to be sent.

> What is the property of AppointmentItem Object, that changes the meeting host?

The easiest way is to create an appointment item in the calendar folder which belongs to a particular account. What code do you use for creating appointment items?

The [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article explains all possible ways for creating appointment items in Outlook. Try to get the right folder and use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028.aspx) method of the `Items` class. For example:

```
 items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
```

The [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `Store` class returns a Folder object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the FolderType argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Comment: Sadly, calling `.Save()` changes nothing.  When I create the appointment with the `ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)` method, it gets the folder of the wrong account again.  The "default calendar folder" is the default calendar of the account that I *don't* have set as my default.  Weird.

Comment: When you create an appointment via the ribbon in Outlook, the "From" when you invite attendees depends on the account associated with the folder you were in when you clicked on the button, so if you're in account A's inbox then "From" is account A, same for account B.  I presume Outlook itself is getting the "account associated with the currently-selected folder" then using that as the "From" account somehow.

Comment: You need to use the `Store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)` method which  belongs to another acount. In your comment you used a `Namespace`, not `Store`.

Comment: And how do I get access to `Store`?  It's just an interface.

Comment: You can use the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property of the `Namespace` class

Comment: OK but that still doesn't tell me what account the currently-selected folder belongs to?

Comment: The `Account` class provides the `DeliveryStore` property which returns a `Store` object that represents the default delivery store for the account. So, you may compare stores and figure out to which account it belongs (if so).